# how to change a custom buttons image when the button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm making a new app, and for one of my modes i want to change the image of a custom button  by pressing the button.i have this custom button setup with an image, and i want to change the image when i press the button. any tips?

Comment: Maybe you could show what you have tried so far? It will increase the chance you receive an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Interface Builder select your button, in Attributes inspector change State Config to "Highlighted" and now you can define highlighted image (along with some other properties).

Via code:

```
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-h.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you! That's exactly what I've been wanting to do!